# com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Can't pass in a Cognito token

Tags: android, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am using developer authentication in my android app. After successful login, the server sends the client the `Cognito` token. The intention of this token is to get access to `Amazon S3` for uploading images.

I have created a sample project here: [TestAWSCognito](https://github.com/abdullahumer/TestAWSCognito)

Here is the snippet code where I am trying to create AmazonS3Client:

```
String identityPoolId = "eu-west-1:289fd4a0-2236-4ff4-9c2b-61c93e60bf0a";

AmazonS3Client testClient = null;

Map<String, String> loginsMap = new HashMap<>();
loginsMap.put("cognito-identity.amazonaws.com", "eyJraWQiOiJldS13ZXN0LTExIiwidHlwIjoiSldTIiwiYWxnIjoiUlM1MTIifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJldS13ZXN0LTE6MjkyM2IxYWQtNGNiYS00ZTFmLWEyY2YtZGIyNDVmM2Q3NWJiIiwiYXVkIjoiZXUtd2VzdC0xOjI4OWZkNGEwLTIyMzYtNGZmNC05YzJiLTYxYzkzZTYwYmYwYSIsImFtciI6WyJhdXRoZW50aWNhdGVkIiwiZ3JhcGhxbC5oYXJhaiIsImdyYXBocWwuaGFyYWo6ZXUtd2VzdC0xOjI4OWZkNGEwLTIyMzYtNGZmNC05YzJiLTYxYzkzZTYwYmYwYTo1NjI4NDAiXSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jb2duaXRvLWlkZW50aXR5LmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1NDUxNDgzMTYsImlhdCI6MTU0NTA2MTkxNn0.V-iZeAQdsdMb9LkzYNucka5PEYRMBKKTGm5CzZIJYg8Z5ehcq562JbXGJWr7Yea-w2APsbpVxgP8EjHxSLjsMggk2FdVd-m8YhNFwBYL91oph-wFiAIxLVginD3t3_EhmkPduXZgM1mwH1_yNsGqpBY4nr15cgjqLvfyb4t-QJADFFyjd2qpIUoNzU2EQ5ypEKmbVdgOeLCIe6a-L09yzO-M1xdC0Onc8fs5ELOISR8FA5YFJYIgyqfSz9wDmz929rmCV9EjFdNC3Jd_hSC_Ofp6NYjiW1HRTU0a2C3Z3FCNJFzKppQSUt78MWrJblhHJSEboeMoKhzxmkA0VPgNjg");


CognitoCredentialsProvider cognitoCredentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(getApplicationContext(), identityPoolId, Regions.EU_WEST_1);
cognitoCredentialsProvider.setLogins(loginsMap);

try {
    AmazonS3Client testClient = new AmazonS3Client(cognitoCredentialsProvider.getCredentials());

    if (testClient != null) {
        return testClient;
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The `token` and `identityPoolId` are still valid.

When creating the `AmazonS3Client` it returns an exception: `com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Can't pass in a Cognito token. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: af373152-0452-11e9-b8c4-c3f49006c33b)`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to assign AmazonCognito specific roles for the user/role that you are using while doing the above operations.

Comment: @Deepthi I will have to confirm that with the server developer.

Comment: Yes, look at these policies: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-reference-cognito.html